# Выбор функций в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, matplotlib, qradiobutton

Делаю *GUI* для одной программы, но сделано только для одной функции `Rs()`,

`def Rs(self, x):return 1.2 * np.sin(3 * np.pi * x / 2.) + 0.5 * np.sin(np.pi * x / 3.) * np.sin(np.pi * x / 2.)`

, а нужно добавить еще 4 ресурса

`return 0.5*np.sin(3*np.pi*x/2.)+0.5*np.sin(1*np.pi*x/3.)+np.sin(1.*np.pi*x/2.)`

`return 1.5*np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)+0.5*np.sin(1*np.pi*x/2.)*np.sin(2.*np.pi*x/1.)`

`return 1.2 * np.sin(3 * np.pi * x / 2.) + 0.5 * np.sin(np.pi * x / 3.) * np.sin(np.pi * x / 2.)`

`return 0.5*np.sin(3*np.pi*x/2.)-0.2*np.sin(2*np.pi*x/2.)-np.sin(3.*np.pi*x/3.)`

пока что можно менять его только раскомментировав, а надо чтобы можно было прямо в программе менять ресурс.

Возможно ли это вообще реализовать в *PyQt5*?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import pylab
import time


class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        super().__init__(self.fig)

        self.p = parent                                                     
        
    def e1(self, u, v):
        return self.p.a11 + self.p.a12 * u * v

    def e2(self, u, v):
        return self.p.a21 + self.p.a22 * u * v

    def f1(self, u, v):
        return u * (self.p.m1-self.p.d1) + v * self.p.d1 - self.p.c1 * u * u - self.p.h1 * u - self.p.b1
        
    def f2(self, u, v):
        return v * (self.p.m2-self.p.d2) + u * self.p.d2 - self.p.c2 * v * v

    def Rs(self, x):
#2 zone
    #return 0.5*np.sin(3*np.pi*x/2.)+0.5*np.sin(1*np.pi*x/3.)+np.sin(1.*np.pi*x/2.)
    #return 1.5*np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)+0.5*np.sin(1*np.pi*x/2.)*np.sin(2.*np.pi*x/1.)
    #return 1.2 * np.sin(3 * np.pi * x / 2.) + 0.5 * np.sin(np.pi * x / 3.) * np.sin(np.pi * x / 2.)
    #1 zone
    #return 0.5*np.sin(3*np.pi*x/2.)-0.2*np.sin(2*np.pi*x/2.)-np.sin(3.*np.pi*x/3.)
    return 1.5*np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)-0.5*np.sin(1*np.pi*x/2.)*np.sin(2.*np.pi*x/2.)
    
        
    def plot(self):
        self.axes.cla()
        plt = self.axes     
        tst = time.perf_counter()
        
        self.p.a[0] = 0.
        self.p.b[0] = 0.
        for i in range(0, self.p.N1+1):
            self.p.x[i] = i * self.p.h
            self.p.y[i] = self.p.ky1 * np.exp(self.p.ky2 * \
                          (((i * self.p.h / self.p.ky3) -self.p.ky4) ** self.p.ky5))
            self.p.v[i] = self.p.kv1 * np.exp(self.p.kv2 * \
                          (((i * self.p.h / self.p.kv3) - self.p.kv4) ** self.p.kv5))

        self.p.x = np.linspace(0, self.p.l, self.p.N1+1)
        R = self.Rs(self.p.x)
        
        plt.axis([0., self.p.l, 0.0, 2.5])
        
        plt.plot(self.p.x, self.p.y, 'b-', label='$u^0(x)$')
        plt.plot(self.p.x, self.p.v, 'g--', label='$v^0(x)$')
        plt.plot(self.p.x, R, 'k-.', label='$r(x)$')
        
        plt.legend(loc=0)
        plt.set_xlabel('$x$')
        plt.set_ylabel('$u,v,r$')
        plt.grid(True)
        
        pylab.ion()
        self.p.x = np.linspace(0, self.p.l, self.p.N1+1)

        for j in range(1, self.p.N2+1):
            for i in range(1, self.p.N1):
                e11 = (self.e1(self.p.y[i], self.p.v[i]) + self.e1(self.p.y[i+1], self.p.v[i+1])) / 2.
                e12 = (self.e1(self.p.y[i], self.p.v[i]) + self.e1(self.p.y[i-1], self.p.v[i-1])) / 2.
                aa = e12 / self.p.rr
                bb = e11 / self.p.rr
                cc = aa + bb + 1
                r12 = self.p.p1 / self.p.rr
                self.p.a[i] = bb / (cc-aa*self.p.a[i-1])
                d = self.p.t*self.f1(self.p.y[i], self.p.v[i])-r12*0.5 * \
                    ((self.p.y[i]+self.p.y[i+1])*(self.p.v[i+1]-self.p.v[i]) - \
                    (self.p.y[i]+self.p.y[i-1])*(self.p.v[i]-self.p.v[i-1]))+self.p.y[i]- \
                    (self.p.q1/self.p.rr)*0.5*((self.p.y[i]+self.p.y[i+1]) * \
                    (R[i+1]-R[i]) - (self.p.y[i]+self.p.y[i-1])*(R[i]-R[i-1]))
                self.p.b[i] = (aa*self.p.b[i-1]+d)/(cc-aa*self.p.a[i-1])
            for ii in range(1, self.p.N1+1):
                i = self.p.N1-ii
                self.p.y[i] = self.p.a[i]*self.p.y[i+1]+self.p.b[i]

            for i in range(0,self.p.N1+1):
                if self.p.y[i]<0: self.p.y[i]=0

            for i in range(1,self.p.N1):
                e21 = (self.e2(self.p.y[i],self.p.v[i])+self.e2(self.p.y[i+1],self.p.v[i+1]))/2.
                e22 = (self.e2(self.p.y[i],self.p.v[i])+self.e2(self.p.y[i-1],self.p.v[i-1]))/2.
                aa = e22 / self.p.rr
                bb = e21 / self.p.rr
                cc = aa + bb + 1
                r12 = self.p.p2 / self.p.rr
                self.p.a[i] = bb / (cc-aa*self.p.a[i-1])
                d = self.p.t*self.f2(self.p.y[i],self.p.v[i])-r12*0.5 * \
                    ((self.p.v[i]+self.p.v[i+1])*(self.p.y[i+1]-self.p.y[i]) - \
                    (self.p.v[i]+self.p.v[i-1])*(self.p.y[i]-self.p.y[i-1]))+self.p.v[i]- \
                    (self.p.q2/self.p.rr)*0.5*((self.p.v[i]+self.p.v[i+1]) * \
                    (R[i+1]-R[i]) - (self.p.v[i]+self.p.v[i-1])*(R[i]-R[i-1]))
                self.p.b[i] = (aa*self.p.b[i-1]+d)/(cc-aa*self.p.a[i-1])
            for ii in range(1,self.p.N1+1):
                i = self.p.N1 - ii
                self.p.v[i] = self.p.a[i] * self.p.v[i+1] + self.p.b[i]

            for i in range(0, self.p.N1+1):
                if self.p.v[i]<0: self.p.v[i]=0
            
            plt.plot(self.p.x, R, 'k-.')
            plt.grid(True)
            
            plt.axis([0., self.p.l, 0.0, 2.5])
            plt.axis([0., self.p.l, 0.0, 2.5])
            plt.plot(self.p.x, self.p.y, 'b-', label='$u$')
            plt.plot(self.p.x, self.p.v, 'g--', label='$v$')
            plt.plot(self.p.x, R, 'k-.', label='$r$')
             
            app.processEvents()                                              
            self.draw()

            if not self.p.flag:
                break

        dt = time.perf_counter() - tst
        print ("N2 = %i, N1 = %i, time solution = %1.3e, h = %1.3e" % (self.p.N2, self.p.N1, dt, self.p.h))


class App(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self._global()                                                       
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)                                      
        self.flag = True                                                     
        self.initUI()

    def _global(self):
        self.ky1 = 0.8
        self.ky2 = -80.0
        self.ky3 = 1.99
        self.ky4 = 0.3
        self.ky5 = 2.0
        self.kv1 = 1.9
        self.kv2 = -80.0
        self.kv3 = 1.8
        self.kv4 = 0.5
        self.kv5 = 2.0

        self.N1 = 50
        self.tt = 20.
        self.l = 2.
        self.h = self.l / self.N1
        self.N2 = 50
        self.t = self.tt / self.N2
        self.hh = self.h * self.h
        self.rr = self.hh / self.t

        self.a11 = 0.03
        self.a12 = 0.01
        self.p1 = 0.03
        self.a21 = 0.03
        self.a22 = 0.01
        self.p2 = 0.03
        self.q1 = 0.05
        self.q2 = 0.05

        self.m1 = 0.75
        self.m2 = 1.1
        self.d1 = 0.7
        self.d2 = 0.5
        self.c1 = 0.25
        self.c2 = 0.65
        self.h1 = 0.15
        self.b1 = 0.67

        self.x = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
        self.y = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
        self.v = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
        self.a = np.zeros((self.N1), 'float')
        self.b = np.zeros((self.N1), 'float')
        self.z = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')

    def initUI(self):
        self.m = PlotCanvas(self, width=5, height=4)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.m, 0, 0) 
        
        self.le_ky1  = QLineEdit('0.8', self)
        self.le_ky2  = QLineEdit('-80.0', self)
        self.le_ky3  = QLineEdit('1.99', self)
        self.le_ky4  = QLineEdit('0.3', self)
        self.le_ky5  = QLineEdit('2.0', self)
        self.le_kv1  = QLineEdit('1.9', self)
        self.le_kv2  = QLineEdit('-80.0', self)
        self.le_kv3  = QLineEdit('1.8', self)
        self.le_kv4  = QLineEdit('0.5', self)
        self.le_kv5  = QLineEdit('2.0', self)
        self.le_a11 = QLineEdit('0.03',self)
        self.le_a12 = QLineEdit('0.01',self)
        self.le_p1  = QLineEdit('0.03',self)
        self.le_a21 = QLineEdit('0.03',self)
        self.le_a22 = QLineEdit('0.01',self)
        self.le_p2  = QLineEdit('0.03',self)
        self.le_q1  = QLineEdit('0.05',self)
        self.le_q2  = QLineEdit('0.05',self)
        self.le_m1  = QLineEdit('0.75',self)
        self.le_m2  = QLineEdit('1.1',self)
        self.le_d1  = QLineEdit('0.7',self)
        self.le_d2  = QLineEdit('0.5',self)
        self.le_c1  = QLineEdit('0.25',self)
        self.le_c2  = QLineEdit('0.65',self)
        self.le_h1  = QLineEdit('0.15',self)
        self.le_b1  = QLineEdit('0.67',self)
        
        button = QPushButton('Start', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.initVars)
        
        formLayout = QFormLayout()  
        formLayout.setVerticalSpacing(1)        
        formLayout.addRow('ky1:', self.le_ky1)
        formLayout.addRow('ky2:', self.le_ky2)
        formLayout.addRow('ky3:', self.le_ky3)
        formLayout.addRow('ky4:', self.le_ky4)
        formLayout.addRow('ky5:', self.le_ky5)
        formLayout.addRow('kv1:', self.le_kv1)
        formLayout.addRow('kv2:', self.le_kv2)
        formLayout.addRow('kv3:', self.le_kv3)
        formLayout.addRow('kv4:', self.le_kv4)
        formLayout.addRow('kv5:', self.le_kv5)
        formLayout.addRow('a11:', self.le_a11)
        formLayout.addRow('a12:', self.le_a12)
        formLayout.addRow('p1:', self.le_p1)
        formLayout.addRow('a21:', self.le_a21)
        formLayout.addRow('a22:', self.le_a22)
        formLayout.addRow('p2:', self.le_p2)
        formLayout.addRow('q1:', self.le_q1)
        formLayout.addRow('q2:', self.le_q2)
        formLayout.addRow('m1:', self.le_m1)
        formLayout.addRow('m2:', self.le_m2)
        formLayout.addRow('d1:', self.le_d1)
        formLayout.addRow('d2:', self.le_d2)
        formLayout.addRow('c1:', self.le_c1)
        formLayout.addRow('c2:', self.le_c2)
        formLayout.addRow('h1:', self.le_h1)
        formLayout.addRow('b1:', self.le_b1)
        formLayout.addRow('', button)
        
        self.layout.addLayout(formLayout, 0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 0)

    def initVars(self):
        self.ky1 = float(self.le_ky1.text())
        self.ky2 = float(self.le_ky2.text())
        self.ky3 = float(self.le_ky3.text())
        self.ky4 = float(self.le_ky4.text())
        self.ky5 = float(self.le_ky5.text())
        self.kv1 = float(self.le_kv1.text())
        self.kv2 = float(self.le_kv2.text())
        self.kv3 = float(self.le_kv3.text())
        self.kv4 = float(self.le_kv4.text())
        self.kv5 = float(self.le_kv5.text())

        self.a11 = float(self.le_a11.text())
        self.a12 = float(self.le_a12.text())
        self.p1  = float(self.le_p1 .text())
        self.a21 = float(self.le_a21.text())
        self.a22 = float(self.le_a22.text())
        self.p2  = float(self.le_p2 .text())
        self.q1  = float(self.le_q1 .text())
        self.q2  = float(self.le_q2 .text())
        self.m1  = float(self.le_m1 .text())
        self.m2  = float(self.le_m2 .text())
        self.d1  = float(self.le_d1 .text())
        self.d2  = float(self.le_d2 .text())
        self.c1  = float(self.le_c1 .text())
        self.c2  = float(self.le_c2 .text())
        self.h1  = float(self.le_h1 .text())
        self.b1  = float(self.le_b1 .text())

        if self.kv4 > 2 or self.kv4 < 0:
            QMessageBox.about(self, "Ошибка", "Значение kv4 должно быть от 0 до 2")
        else:
            self.h = self.l / self.N1
            self.t = self.tt / self.N2
            self.hh = self.h * self.h
            self.rr = self.hh / self.t
            self.x = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
            self.y = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
            self.v = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
            self.a = np.zeros((self.N1), 'float')
            self.b = np.zeros((self.N1), 'float')
            self.z = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
            
            self.m.plot()                                   
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.flag = False
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(800, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, я отметил для вас строки, которые реализуют вариант решения.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
import pylab
import time


class PlotCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, rbtns, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):          # +++ rbtns
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        super().__init__(self.fig)

        self.p = parent
        self.rbtns = rbtns                                                       # +++ 
        
    def e1(self, u, v):
        return self.p.a11 + self.p.a12 * u * v

    def e2(self, u, v):
        return self.p.a21 + self.p.a22 * u * v

    def f1(self, u, v):
        return u * (self.p.m1-self.p.d1) + v * self.p.d1 - self.p.c1 * u * u - self.p.h1 * u - self.p.b1
        
    def f2(self, u, v):
        return v * (self.p.m2-self.p.d2) + u * self.p.d2 - self.p.c2 * v * v

    def Rs(self, x):
# +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    
#2 zone
        if self.rbtns[2].isChecked():
            return 0.5*np.sin(3*np.pi*x/2.)+0.5*np.sin(1*np.pi*x/3.)+np.sin(1.*np.pi*x/2.)
        elif self.rbtns[3].isChecked():
            return 1.5*np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)+0.5*np.sin(1*np.pi*x/2.)*np.sin(2.*np.pi*x/1.)
        elif self.rbtns[4].isChecked():
            return 1.2 * np.sin(3 * np.pi * x / 2.) + 0.5 * np.sin(np.pi * x / 3.) * np.sin(np.pi * x / 2.)
#1 zone
        elif self.rbtns[0].isChecked():
            return 0.5*np.sin(3*np.pi*x/2.)-0.2*np.sin(2*np.pi*x/2.)-np.sin(3.*np.pi*x/3.)
        elif self.rbtns[1].isChecked():
            return 1.5*np.sin(np.pi*x/2.)-0.5*np.sin(1*np.pi*x/2.)*np.sin(2.*np.pi*x/2.)
# +++  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^    
        
    def plot(self):
        self.axes.cla()
        plt = self.axes     
        tst = time.perf_counter()
        
        self.p.a[0] = 0.
        self.p.b[0] = 0.
        for i in range(0, self.p.N1+1):
            self.p.x[i] = i * self.p.h
            self.p.y[i] = self.p.ky1 * np.exp(self.p.ky2 * \
                          (((i * self.p.h / self.p.ky3) -self.p.ky4) ** self.p.ky5))
            self.p.v[i] = self.p.kv1 * np.exp(self.p.kv2 * \
                          (((i * self.p.h / self.p.kv3) - self.p.kv4) ** self.p.kv5))

        self.p.x = np.linspace(0, self.p.l, self.p.N1+1)
# Rs
        R = self.Rs(self.p.x)
        
        plt.axis([0., self.p.l, 0.0, 2.5])
        
        plt.plot(self.p.x, self.p.y, 'b-', label='$u^0(x)$')
        plt.plot(self.p.x, self.p.v, 'g--', label='$v^0(x)$')
        plt.plot(self.p.x, R, 'k-.', label='$r(x)$')
        
        plt.legend(loc=0)
        plt.set_xlabel('$x$')
        plt.set_ylabel('$u,v,r$')
        plt.grid(True)
        
        pylab.ion()
        self.p.x = np.linspace(0, self.p.l, self.p.N1+1)

        for j in range(1, self.p.N2+1):
            for i in range(1, self.p.N1):
                e11 = (self.e1(self.p.y[i], self.p.v[i]) + self.e1(self.p.y[i+1], self.p.v[i+1])) / 2.
                e12 = (self.e1(self.p.y[i], self.p.v[i]) + self.e1(self.p.y[i-1], self.p.v[i-1])) / 2.
                aa = e12 / self.p.rr
                bb = e11 / self.p.rr
                cc = aa + bb + 1
                r12 = self.p.p1 / self.p.rr
                self.p.a[i] = bb / (cc-aa*self.p.a[i-1])
                d = self.p.t*self.f1(self.p.y[i], self.p.v[i])-r12*0.5 * \
                    ((self.p.y[i]+self.p.y[i+1])*(self.p.v[i+1]-self.p.v[i]) - \
                    (self.p.y[i]+self.p.y[i-1])*(self.p.v[i]-self.p.v[i-1]))+self.p.y[i]- \
                    (self.p.q1/self.p.rr)*0.5*((self.p.y[i]+self.p.y[i+1]) * \
                    (R[i+1]-R[i]) - (self.p.y[i]+self.p.y[i-1])*(R[i]-R[i-1]))
                self.p.b[i] = (aa*self.p.b[i-1]+d)/(cc-aa*self.p.a[i-1])
            for ii in range(1, self.p.N1+1):
                i = self.p.N1-ii
                self.p.y[i] = self.p.a[i]*self.p.y[i+1]+self.p.b[i]

            for i in range(0,self.p.N1+1):
                if self.p.y[i]<0: self.p.y[i]=0

            for i in range(1,self.p.N1):
                e21 = (self.e2(self.p.y[i],self.p.v[i])+self.e2(self.p.y[i+1],self.p.v[i+1]))/2.
                e22 = (self.e2(self.p.y[i],self.p.v[i])+self.e2(self.p.y[i-1],self.p.v[i-1]))/2.
                aa = e22 / self.p.rr
                bb = e21 / self.p.rr
                cc = aa + bb + 1
                r12 = self.p.p2 / self.p.rr
                self.p.a[i] = bb / (cc-aa*self.p.a[i-1])
                d = self.p.t*self.f2(self.p.y[i],self.p.v[i])-r12*0.5 * \
                    ((self.p.v[i]+self.p.v[i+1])*(self.p.y[i+1]-self.p.y[i]) - \
                    (self.p.v[i]+self.p.v[i-1])*(self.p.y[i]-self.p.y[i-1]))+self.p.v[i]- \
                    (self.p.q2/self.p.rr)*0.5*((self.p.v[i]+self.p.v[i+1]) * \
                    (R[i+1]-R[i]) - (self.p.v[i]+self.p.v[i-1])*(R[i]-R[i-1]))
                self.p.b[i] = (aa*self.p.b[i-1]+d)/(cc-aa*self.p.a[i-1])
            for ii in range(1,self.p.N1+1):
                i = self.p.N1 - ii
                self.p.v[i] = self.p.a[i] * self.p.v[i+1] + self.p.b[i]

            for i in range(0, self.p.N1+1):
                if self.p.v[i]<0: self.p.v[i]=0
            
            plt.plot(self.p.x, R, 'k-.')
            plt.grid(True)
            
            plt.axis([0., self.p.l, 0.0, 2.5])
            plt.axis([0., self.p.l, 0.0, 2.5])
            plt.plot(self.p.x, self.p.y, 'b-', label='$u$')
            plt.plot(self.p.x, self.p.v, 'g--', label='$v$')
            plt.plot(self.p.x, R, 'k-.', label='$r$')
            
            app.processEvents()                                              
            self.draw()

            if not self.p.flag:
                break

        dt = time.perf_counter() - tst
        print("N2 = %i, N1 = %i, time solution = %1.3e, h = %1.3e" % (self.p.N2, self.p.N1, dt, self.p.h))


class App(QWidget):    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self._global()                                                       
        self.layout = QGridLayout(self)                                      
        self.flag = True                                                     
        self.initUI()

    def _global(self):
        self.ky1 = 0.8
        self.ky2 = -80.0
        self.ky3 = 1.99
        self.ky4 = 0.3
        self.ky5 = 2.0
        self.kv1 = 1.9
        self.kv2 = -80.0
        self.kv3 = 1.8
        self.kv4 = 0.5
        self.kv5 = 2.0

        self.N1 = 50
        self.tt = 20.
        self.l = 2.
        self.h = self.l / self.N1
        self.N2 = 50
        self.t = self.tt / self.N2
        self.hh = self.h * self.h
        self.rr = self.hh / self.t

        self.a11 = 0.03
        self.a12 = 0.01
        self.p1 = 0.03
        self.a21 = 0.03
        self.a22 = 0.01
        self.p2 = 0.03
        self.q1 = 0.05
        self.q2 = 0.05

        self.m1 = 0.75
        self.m2 = 1.1
        self.d1 = 0.7
        self.d2 = 0.5
        self.c1 = 0.25
        self.c2 = 0.65
        self.h1 = 0.15
        self.b1 = 0.67

        self.x = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
        self.y = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
        self.v = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
        self.a = np.zeros((self.N1), 'float')
        self.b = np.zeros((self.N1), 'float')
        self.z = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
        
# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv 
        self.rbtns = [
            QRadioButton('z11'),
            QRadioButton('z12'),
            QRadioButton('z21'),
            QRadioButton('z22'),
            QRadioButton('z23'),
        ]
        self.rbtns[1].setChecked(True)
        self.group_rb = QButtonGroup(self)
        self.h_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        for rb in self.rbtns:
            self.h_layout.addWidget(rb)
            self.group_rb.addButton(rb)   
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      

    def initUI(self):
        self.m = PlotCanvas(self.rbtns, self, width=5, height=4)                 # +++ self.rbtns
        self.layout.addWidget(self.m, 0, 0) 
        
        self.le_ky1  = QLineEdit('0.8', self)
        self.le_ky2  = QLineEdit('-80.0', self)
        self.le_ky3  = QLineEdit('1.99', self)
        self.le_ky4  = QLineEdit('0.3', self)
        self.le_ky5  = QLineEdit('2.0', self)
        self.le_kv1  = QLineEdit('1.9', self)
        self.le_kv2  = QLineEdit('-80.0', self)
        self.le_kv3  = QLineEdit('1.8', self)
        self.le_kv4  = QLineEdit('0.5', self)
        self.le_kv5  = QLineEdit('2.0', self)
        self.le_a11 = QLineEdit('0.03',self)
        self.le_a12 = QLineEdit('0.01',self)
        self.le_p1  = QLineEdit('0.03',self)
        self.le_a21 = QLineEdit('0.03',self)
        self.le_a22 = QLineEdit('0.01',self)
        self.le_p2  = QLineEdit('0.03',self)
        self.le_q1  = QLineEdit('0.05',self)
        self.le_q2  = QLineEdit('0.05',self)
        self.le_m1  = QLineEdit('0.75',self)
        self.le_m2  = QLineEdit('1.1',self)
        self.le_d1  = QLineEdit('0.7',self)
        self.le_d2  = QLineEdit('0.5',self)
        self.le_c1  = QLineEdit('0.25',self)
        self.le_c2  = QLineEdit('0.65',self)
        self.le_h1  = QLineEdit('0.15',self)
        self.le_b1  = QLineEdit('0.67',self)
        
        button = QPushButton('Start', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.initVars)
        
        formLayout = QFormLayout()  
        formLayout.setVerticalSpacing(1)        
        formLayout.addRow('ky1:', self.le_ky1)
        formLayout.addRow('ky2:', self.le_ky2)
        formLayout.addRow('ky3:', self.le_ky3)
        formLayout.addRow('ky4:', self.le_ky4)
        formLayout.addRow('ky5:', self.le_ky5)
        formLayout.addRow('kv1:', self.le_kv1)
        formLayout.addRow('kv2:', self.le_kv2)
        formLayout.addRow('kv3:', self.le_kv3)
        formLayout.addRow('kv4:', self.le_kv4)
        formLayout.addRow('kv5:', self.le_kv5)
        formLayout.addRow('a11:', self.le_a11)
        formLayout.addRow('a12:', self.le_a12)
        formLayout.addRow('p1:', self.le_p1)
        formLayout.addRow('a21:', self.le_a21)
        formLayout.addRow('a22:', self.le_a22)
        formLayout.addRow('p2:', self.le_p2)
        formLayout.addRow('q1:', self.le_q1)
        formLayout.addRow('q2:', self.le_q2)
        formLayout.addRow('m1:', self.le_m1)
        formLayout.addRow('m2:', self.le_m2)
        formLayout.addRow('d1:', self.le_d1)
        formLayout.addRow('d2:', self.le_d2)
        formLayout.addRow('c1:', self.le_c1)
        formLayout.addRow('c2:', self.le_c2)
        formLayout.addRow('h1:', self.le_h1)
        formLayout.addRow('b1:', self.le_b1)

# +++  vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        
        formLayout.addRow(QLabel(
            '<h3 style="color: red;">Выберите ресурс</h3>', alignment=Qt.AlignCenter))
        formLayout.addRow(self.h_layout)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^         
        
        formLayout.addRow('', button)
        
        self.layout.addLayout(formLayout, 0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(0, 1)
        self.layout.setColumnStretch(1, 0)

    def initVars(self):
        self.ky1 = float(self.le_ky1.text())
        self.ky2 = float(self.le_ky2.text())
        self.ky3 = float(self.le_ky3.text())
        self.ky4 = float(self.le_ky4.text())
        self.ky5 = float(self.le_ky5.text())
        self.kv1 = float(self.le_kv1.text())
        self.kv2 = float(self.le_kv2.text())
        self.kv3 = float(self.le_kv3.text())
        self.kv4 = float(self.le_kv4.text())
        self.kv5 = float(self.le_kv5.text())

        self.a11 = float(self.le_a11.text())
        self.a12 = float(self.le_a12.text())
        self.p1  = float(self.le_p1 .text())
        self.a21 = float(self.le_a21.text())
        self.a22 = float(self.le_a22.text())
        self.p2  = float(self.le_p2 .text())
        self.q1  = float(self.le_q1 .text())
        self.q2  = float(self.le_q2 .text())
        self.m1  = float(self.le_m1 .text())
        self.m2  = float(self.le_m2 .text())
        self.d1  = float(self.le_d1 .text())
        self.d2  = float(self.le_d2 .text())
        self.c1  = float(self.le_c1 .text())
        self.c2  = float(self.le_c2 .text())
        self.h1  = float(self.le_h1 .text())
        self.b1  = float(self.le_b1 .text())

        if self.kv4 > 2 or self.kv4 < 0:
            QMessageBox.about(self, "Ошибка", "Значение kv4 должно быть от 0 до 2")
        else:
            self.h = self.l / self.N1
            self.t = self.tt / self.N2
            self.hh = self.h * self.h
            self.rr = self.hh / self.t
            self.x = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
            self.y = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
            self.v = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
            self.a = np.zeros((self.N1), 'float')
            self.b = np.zeros((self.N1), 'float')
            self.z = np.zeros((self.N1+1), 'float')
            
            self.m.plot()                                   
        
    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.flag = False
            

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.resize(800, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы даже не представляете насколько вы мне помогли, без Вас я бы не справился, большое спасибо!

Comment: @Gltockus пожалуйста

Comment: @Gltockus sorry, я слабо понимаю что у вас написано в коде и что вам надо сделать. Попробуйте задать новый вопрос, но вы должны очень четко расписать что делает ваша задача. что вы хотите сделать, но конечно должна быть попытка вашей реализации задуманного.

Comment: Хорошо, можете тогда по вашему коду написать комментарии не по всему коду, а именно по построении gui'а?

Comment: пожалуйста можете помочь с этим вопросом? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1294293/Очень-сильно-тормозит-анимация2d-matplotlib-с-pyqt5